# What makes someone an introvert or an extrovert?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, introversion, extraversion

While I can understand that this may not be all black and white - i.e. there are also definitive ambiverts - I'd just been wondering for a while now, what are the possible factors that help in defining and forming the introvert and extrovert personality features in an individual?

Specifically, to what extent does someone's childhood and upbringing contribute to their preferred mode of operation?

Comment: This question is a bit broad for this site.  Maybe you should split the question up in order to narrow the field of information required as writing an answer for this would take more than a few paragraphs to give more than a general answer.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for responding. The question has now been edited to focus just on an individual's early years. I'd also be very interested in understanding the impact of genetics on one's personality features. However, as suggested, that bit of the question is now reserved for another day. Thank you.